# Visual Studio C++ - running separate .cpp files?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I just started using Visual Studio (Enterprise), more specifically C and C++ Programming. I was wondering, since I'm using mainly simple C programming and nothing OOP, is it possible to have multiple .cpp files in the same solution and/or project, and compile/run them separately.

I have a lot of C programs to write and I'm hoping I won't have to create a whole solution for each simple main function. I know this might be a dumb question but I'm still new to the structure of Visual Studio, any help would greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need separate solutions, but separate projects in one (or more, if you like) solution. See [Solutions and Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b142f8e7.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a single solution with multiple project. Each project has its own main.
This is a weakness of visual studio, you can not create a project with several main.

Comment: Why "weakness" ? It doesn't make sense to have several functions with the same name winthin one project.

Comment: I see, thanks. I'm sure there's a way to run separate projects (in the same solution) by themselves, but I can't seem to find how. Any ideas?

Comment: @MichaelWalz in other IDE like netbeans you can change the makefile of your project to have ONE project with several main files, when you compile you get several executable/dll or whatever you want.

Comment: @Logan you can use multiple startup project, to run your projects separately. Goto solution explorer->properties->common properties->startup project enable multiple startup project. This link can help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165413.aspx

Comment: @Pumkko you can do this in Visual Studio, it's called "solution". A solution can contain as many projects as you want, and each project can contain exactly one main function. But you know that already.